# Populate Django Model Choice Field In __init__ or save?

Tags: django, model, save, init

I want to set the choices for one of my fields based on the keyword arguments given to the model constructor. Does it make more sense to do this in the Model `__init__` method or the `save()` method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd want to do this in your __init__

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *don't* want to do this in `__init__()`, seeing as how the model may not reflect what's actually in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends.  Do you want it the dependent assignment to happen when you first create an instance of your model or do you want it to happen every time the model is saved?  Putting it in an overridden `save` will give you a stronger guarantee that your dependent data won't get out of sync (so long as you don't use `update()` or drop down to raw SQL).

Comment: I know that is the tradeoff with __init__ vs save(). It seems like it could go either way depending on how you use the model. Thanks for your response.